# wonky spacing when making a list

Tags: spacing

I'm trying to make a list with only a minor indent but I cant seem to figure it out. I'm new(I started using latex today) so I'm trying to get used to it. anyway this is what I've done but it looks wonky especially the `$$\chi\{2\} = a^2$$`.

```
\text{Let $G$ be a group, and let $G$ = $\mathbb{Z}_5$ $=$ $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Let $\chi:G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ = $\{\mathbb{Z}\in\mathbb{C}:\lvert{\mathbb{Z}\rvert}=1\}$. Now we have: \smallskip}

$$\chi\{0\} = 1$$
$$\chi\{1\} = a$$
$$\chi\{2\} = a^2$$
$$\chi\{3\} = a^3$$
$$\chi\{4\} = a^4$$
```

Comment: also the chi in the first line is "too low" compared with 'G' so is there a way to fix that?

Comment: also I want to add a=e^(2*pi*I/5) with a^5=1 next to the above list, how can I do this?

Comment: The letter Chi has a depth, it is correct

Comment: @Herbert now I want to do a subscript of chi but it comes out funny: $\chi_0$ how shall I fix this

Comment: Compare `$\chi_0\alpha_0$` It is not funny it is correct

Comment: @Herbert is there a way to get the zero much lower?

Comment: @Herbert this is what I what $\chi_0\(x\)$ but the addition of the brackets, I am getting errors. also I would like to 'push' down the zero on chi as I don't like it the current way

Comment: round parentheses without backslash! `$\chi_0(x)$`

Comment: @A.E Look that double sign `$$` is depreciated. You should use `\[..\]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

    Let $G$ be a group, and let $G = \mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. 
    Let $\chi:G \rightarrow 
        \mathbb{Z} = \{\mathbb{Z}\in\mathbb{C}:\lvert{\mathbb{Z}\rvert}=1\}$. 
    Now we have: 
    %
    \begin{align*}
    \chi\{0\} &= 1\\
    \chi\{1\} &= a\\
    \chi\{2\} &= a^2\\
    \chi\{3\} &= a^3\\
    \chi\{4\} &= a^4
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, can you also read my comments above

Comment: can you please read my comments below on alephzero's answer, this will be appreciated.

Comment: and with the letter complex number "I" when I use the \iota command, it isn't showing the dot on the I, how do I fix this?

Comment: use `\dot\iota`

Comment: The Greek letter iota doesn't have a dot. If you want the letter i, just write an i.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what you want to do, but I suggest you learn about the `amsmath` package, which has many options for formatting math beyond the basic "display an equation" you get with `$$…$$`.

Note, you shouldn't really use `$$…$$`with LaTeX. `\begin{equation}…\end{equation}` (and similar things in `amsmath`) give better vertical spacing in LaTeX.

You should have the documentation for `amsmath` in your TeX installation, but if you can't find it the user guide is here: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf. You can also find tutorials on the web.

Herbert's answer used the `mathtools` package which is an extension to `amsmath` - it's up to you whether you want to "jump in at the deep end" or learn one step at a time!

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

    Let $G$ be a group, and let $G = \mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. 
    Let $\chi:G \rightarrow 
        \mathbb{Z} = \{\mathbb{Z}\in\mathbb{C}:\lvert{\mathbb{Z}\rvert}=1\}$. 
    Now we have: 
    %
    \begin{align*}
    \chi\{0\} &= 1\\
    \chi\{1\} &= a\\
    \chi\{2\} &= a^2\\
    \chi\{3\} &= a^3\\
    \chi\{4\} &= a^4
    \end{align*}
\end{document}

Comment: so from the above code, I want to incorporate the following:with $a=exp\frac{2\pi\iota}{5}$ hence $a^5=1$  but I want this to appear next to chi(2) so how must I do this? also I want the exponent to be shown as an exponent and not "exp" so any tips?

Comment: `\chi\{2\} &= a^2 \text{ with } a = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}} \text{ hence } a^5 = 1 \\ `. Note, you need the spaces around "with," because TeX ignores most spaces in math input - for example the space between the `2` and `\text`. If you want more horizontal space, do `... a^2 \quad \text{with} \quad e = ...` or use `\qquad` for even more space.